# What are my options for packaging a WLCSP IC as a DIP?

Tags: packages, manufacturing, bga, dip

Hypothetically, let's say I have a chip in a super small WLCSP or BGA package that I want to have packaged as a plastic or ceramic DIP. No extra components; just the pads brought out to pins.

Are there companies that will do this on a small scale? Like 100 or 200 chips at a time? What might the setup and manufacturing costs be like?

Comment: So you're looking for something more than a [Breakout Board](https://www.google.com/search?q=wlcsp+breakout+board&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS906US906&oq=wlcsp+breakout+board&aqs=chrome..69i57.9696j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: If you're ok with a stack of header pins, FR4 substrate, and copper interconnect, you can have any PCBA supplier fabricate a board breaking out pads to headers with the chip soldered onto the pads. Or do you need it to necessarily be encapsulated in plastic epoxy or a CERDIP?

Comment: Could "paint" or dip the PCB in epoxy for "encapsulation" at low volume runs.

Comment: For my own purposes, I would definitely just use a PCB. But I'm curious about having actual DIP chips made to re-sell.

Comment: I don't think you'd find joy trying to attach such a package to a chip carrier -- I think your best bet would be a piece of FR4 with legs, and a molded cap that makes it look like a chip.  I'd suggest that if you go there, you think twice before neglecting to put power bypass caps on the carrier.  You *may* get away with leaving them off, but if high speeds are involved, you may well have problems without them.

Comment: @DavidBrown Depending on the market, you might be better off reselling a PCB with some kind of enclosure.  It works for the [$70 Op Amp](https://diyaudiostore.com/collections/parts/products/burson-audio-v6)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many board fab companies have in-house assembly capabilities.  We have done this with the "carrier board" or "breakout board" approach as mentioned above using a board house to do both board fabrication and assembly of the part onto the board.  We paid $25.30 for each finished assembly at quantity 200 (the part in question was $8 at this quantity).  There was a lot charge of $250 and a non-recurring engineering charge of $775.  We employed a high-temperature solder to hold the parts on the board.  The NRE is a one-time charge unless the design is changed, but the lot charge is the same every order with a 200-piece minimum.  We put the legs on ourselves after getting them from the board house.

Comment: I just found a source for DIP lead carrier pins that attach to the side of a PCB, so I think having a PCB printed and assembled by a third-party and then molding the DIP casings myself might be feasible.

Comment: Be sure and watch the solder you use in your assembly or it will reflow when the DIP part is attached.